# C# AddHandler PreviewTextInput

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am building a `xaml` structure within code because I have a variable list
length to input. Everything works really well, but since I am binding a
`TextBox` to an integer, I need to validate input as it happens. The binding
already ignores input that doesn't conform to being an integer, and borders
the `TextBox` in red. But relying on that is messy and I do not like it. I 
want to add and `TextBox.AddHandler()` for `PreviewTextInput`, but I get errors.

```
xTextBox.AddHandler(TextBox.PreviewTextInput, new TextCompositionEventArgs(keyPressDown));
```

> Error - An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

and

> Error - There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'composition' ...

When I write a test program and do the binding within the `xaml` window, it works perfectly. So what am I doing wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
xTextBox.AddHandler(TextBox.PreviewTextInputEvent, new TextCompositionEventHandler(keyPressDown));
```

Or you can just do this instead:

```
xTextBox.PreviewTextInput += keyPressDown;
```

As a side note, having a variable length list of items is not a valid justification for using code-behind over data-binding, if anything it's even more of a reason not to!